# Crontab rake job is not working with whenever gem in ruby

Tags: ruby, rake, cron

This is my crontab file generated by whenever:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/apps/path && RAILS_ENV=production echo "Testing" >> /new

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/apps/path && RAILS_ENV=production rake somegroup:rake_job --silent'
```

The first line is for test only and works as expected. However the rake job in the other line has nothing to do at all. In /var/log/syslog, both jobs are executed. Also tried using the absolute path of rake (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rake), still no luck. Don't know where to find error message. I'm using ubuntu 10.04TS server.

Any thoughts will be appreciated! ;)

J

Comment: Error messages by `cron` are usually emailed to the owner of the crontab.

Comment: You can log the output with ">> log/cron.log 2>&1", so "rake youucommand >> log/cron.log 2>&1" would capture the failing output (or any puts logging type statements you put in.)

Answer (score 0):

are you using rvm and gemsets ?

I think I've found a problem with Whenever and rvm's rvmrc file

Comment: Cheers, I have figured it out. Sorry it was because I didn't load the right ruby. Run this command first, and everything goes fine: source "/usr/local/bin/rvm" && rvm 1.9.2